Help with four colors theorem example
Firstly, I do believe there is a solution, just that I haven't found it, not due to lack of effort (I have spent over two hours on it).
Our professor gave us this image as a riddle to solve. In our attempt, see below photo, we were unable to color the map using only four colors, but would love to be proven wrong. Can anyone else see the solution that I am not seeing?
He refuses to give us an answer as to the solution, and reverse searching doesn't work. Pattern recognition is not my strong suit; please help us.
(PS. To those worried about me needing this for a grade, He has given us similar work and it has never contributed to a grade.)

Secondly, He clarified that four partial circles inside the largest circle are in fact supposed to be touching the two closest curved L shapes, I understand it is a small point of contact but they are making contact

Welcome to MSE! Maybe tell us what you did so far... so we can try to help you.

A way to find a coloring is to find one set of four regions that all touch each other. Once you have found such a set, color them in four different colors. Then look for an uncolored region bordered by three different colors; its color is determined. I've found two different sets of four regions you can start with; maybe you can find one too. Once you find one, the rest of the solution is pretty much routine, at least for this map.

The new map is solved by the same method as the old one, though the solution is different.

Does this work? The rest is symmetric.

Updated version:


You should wait for the OP to try by himself. It's always better to give a good hint and let him/her do the work.

Isn't there a color left for the outer square? Can't be red, can't be yellow, can't be blue,...

Sorry, accidently posted an inaccurate version of the puzzle, I have fixed the original image.

@Kolakoski54 The rest of the square can be the turquoise-ish color (not sure exactly what it is since I'm colorblind, but the color that is not red, yellow, or blue)

I added the updated version
